# If there is a point of proper period 2, prove there is a fixed point p where f(p) = p

Tags: real-analysis

I know that if is continuous on R, and there is a point q in r such that f(f(q)) = q but f(q) =/= q. Prove that there is a fixed point p in R such that f(p) = p.

Comment: Hint: Intermediate Value Theorem. (Also this is probably a duplicate question, try searching on this site...!)

Comment: There is a general theorem for this , so called Sharkovsky theorem - if we set order  $1 < ... 2^n <2^{n-1} < ... <7 < 5 <3$ then if $f$ has a fixed point of the order $n$ and $m < n$ in the sense above then $f$ has fixed point of order $m$. In particular, if $f$ has fixed point of order 3 it has fixed point of any order (Li-York), Clearly, if $f$ has fixed point of order 2 it has a fixed point follows as well.